# What's the probability 2 people sharing a house will get the same disease?

Tags: probability

I am interested in environmental causes for illnesses. Suppose an illness has a prevalence of 0.1% of the population. What's the probability then that 2 people who share the same house will both get this disease?

I tempted to say 0.001x0.001, but not sure it's that simple.

Thanks.

Edit: I should clarify, I am interested in the probability that any 2 people sharing a house will come down with a certain disease, if it can be assumed that there is no environmental link. Then I can compare that to the actual percentage of house-sharers that both have a given illness.

Comment: You are right, if the probabilities are independent. Realistically, they almost certainly are not, and the probability is probably much higher.

Comment: Do you mean that the thing that is causing the probabilities to be dependent is the "enironmental cause"? I am interested in what the probability would be if there were no environmental cause...in this case can I say 0.001x0.001 ?

Comment: If there is no environmental or contagious cause, then your answer seems reasonable to me. But I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to assume some probability model to solve this. A binomial model may be appropriate to solve this if you know the total number of people in the house. You can also go the Bayes route if you have some past information about the dependence of how the disease is spread.

I can't see how you would solve this without additional information, though.